# TYPO3 extension builder multiple images upload not working

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-extensions, extension-builder3

My goal is to create extension using extension builder in TYPO3 7.6.2 version. I created Category Product extension from extension builder document, it works perfect except upload single image.

But I have to create functionality to add multiple images to single product and display images carousel on frontend. But extension builder does not work with file uploads.

I am new in TYPO3, so I don't understand how to add multiple images to that? I read too many documents but did not found perfect solution.

I just want to know the process how to add multiple images to products?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I got the solution to this question.

Go to your extension and follow the steps -

1. /Classes/Domain/Model/YourModel.php

   ```
       /**
        * yourPictures
        *
        * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference>
        * @lazy
        */
       protected $yourPictures = NULL;

       /**
        * Constructor
        *
        * @return AbstractObject
        */
       public function __construct() {
               // ObjectStorage is needed to reference multiple files to one field
               // see also @var before variable and @return before the respective get() method
               $this->yourPictures = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
       }

       /**
        * returns yourPictures
        *
        * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage
        */
       public function getYourPictures() {
               return $this->yourPictures;
       }

       /**
        * sets yourPictures
        *
        * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage $yourPictures
        * @return void
        */
       public function setYourPictures($yourPictures) {
               $this->yourPictures = $yourPictures;
       }
   ```
2. /Configuration/TCA/YourModel.php

   Add field name in `array 'types'` and in `array 'columns'` add this -

```html
       'your_pictures' => array(
                'exclude' => 1,
                'label' => 'LLL:EXT:your_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_yourext_domain_model_yourmodel.your_pictures',
                'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
                        'yourPictures',
                        array('minitems'=>0,'maxitems'=>10),
                        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
                ),
        ),
```

3. /ext_tables.sql

add `my_pictures varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,`

4. To display in fluid template -

```html
<f:for each="{yourDomain.myPictures}" as="pic">
            <f:image src="{pic.originalResource.publicUrl}" alt="{pic.originalResource.alternative}" title="{pic.originalResource.title}" ></f:image>
            {pic.originalResource.description}
    </f:for>
```

Thats it ! Hope it will help someone.

Thanks

Comment: In case the link goes dead, could you post the relevant parts of the link *in* your answer? Many thanks,

Comment: @WaiHaLee  I edited the above answer. Now you can relevant answer.
Thanks

Comment: for everyone reading this: pls use using statements instead of repeating the whole namespaces over and over again... horrible to read